# xcodebuild return value

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm using *xcodebuild* to build a unit test target after an every change which is commited to the SCM and if unit tests are not passed I'd like to notify the person who's introduced the changes. The problem is that even if a unit test target's build fails *xcodebuild* returns 0 as a return value. 
Is there any way to identify that *xccodebuild's* build fails?

Comment: How is your unit test set up? Because the standard Xcode unit testing will fail an xcodebuild. Basically, xcodebuild fails if any of the subcommands return != 0, so I guess it's your test target that returns 0 even when failing.

Comment: AFAIR I followed this guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH20-SW3

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be easy. If the unit test fail, you can write something in a file, so:

1. First you clean the file
2. Than run the unit test.
3. You can create a trick function or use a smart `#define` and if something fail , you write in the file
4. Than is just read the file. If have a problem, you will know

Finally, if have error,  you can fire the employer!